# Finding characters in Classic Dyalog APL character set

Tags: character-encoding, apl, dyalog

In Dyalog APL the character vector ⎕AV contains all characters in the Classic Dyalog APL character set. Where can i find information about what each character in ⎕AV stand for? I'm trying to find out what each control character in the ASCII encoding corresponds to in ⎕AV in order to filter out invalid character entered in a form.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stand for" in "what each character in ⎕AV stand for"? Which Unicode code point it has?

Comment: @Adám Not every character has a meaningful graphical representation. Yes, I mean which ASCII code it has (since I'm only interested in the first 32 ones which coincide with the first Unicode code points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. You can simply apply `⎕UCS` to the characters you're interested in.
2. You can look at the corresponding positions in `⎕AVU`.

Comment: Using ⎕UCS is indeed the solution.